# Xcode 8 does not auto-complete for init methods

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8

I am having trouble getting Xcode 8 with Swift 3 to auto-complete common initialization methods, and was wondering if there is anything I could do to fix the situation.

Specifically, take something like:

```
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
```

The initialization method `String(data:, encoding:)` will not populate.

[Demo Video](https://youtu.be/VdIR5TwF5GU)

Comment: What version of Xcode 8 specifically are you using? I cannot currently reproduce this problem – although in the past I've usually found typing `String.init(` helps wake up the auto-complete for initialisers (and obviously remove the `.init` once it's typed).

Comment: I had similar issues with code completion or when I command + clicked on functions it wouldn't work 50% of the times. Then I updated and all my problems went away...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. `String.init(` is a great suggestion and definitely worked to provide the autocomplete. Is taking out `.init` necessary? I ran the code with `.init` left in and everything worked as expected.

Comment: @Honey I am using 8.2.1. I assume that's the version that worked for you?

Comment: @daspianist yes 8.2.1

Comment: According to Apple, this problem is fixed in Xcode 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it useful to type the actual word `.init` before asking for code completion. Then later, I take it back out again.

Note that Xcode is very choosy; if you go too far and type `.init(` it won't work.

[image]

**EDIT** According to Apple, this problem is fixed in Xcode 10.

Comment: This is a great trick - thanks for capturing the video as well. Quick question - when I ran it out my end, leaving `.init` in there didn't affect any operations. Should there be something that I should watch out for if I keep the `.init` part?

Comment: That's a quasi-religious question. :) You're not _supposed_ to leave it there, but it does no harm as far as I can tell.