# Struct initializer not showing?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, autocomplete, xcode10

evertime when i create a instance of a struct the automatic initializer isn't showing up. I have to type every parameter until it works

```
struct Message {
    private(set) public var id: String!
    private(set) public var timeStamp: String!
}
```

[image]

What can I do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pro tip: Type `TypeName.init` to get the autocomplete to suggest all the available initializers. After finding the one you want and filling out its arguments, you can just remove the `.init`!

Comment: All those implicitly unwrapped optionals are a *really* big red flag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8 does not auto-complete for init methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796212/xcode-8-does-not-auto-complete-for-init-methods)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pro tip: Type `TypeName.init` to get the autocomplete to suggest all the available initializers. After finding the one you want and filling out its arguments, you can just remove the `.init`!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to type Message.init then the autocomplete pops up then i remove .init